# How to filter ng-repeat with values NOT IN another array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angular-filters

**Is there any way to use an Angular filter to compare value with every value from an array?**

```
Categories: <span ng-repeat="c in i.categories | filter: '!'+'myArray' ">{{c}}</span>
```

I would like to display values from `i.categories` that are not in `myArray`:

```
$scope.i = {
  categories: [
    "Europe & Eurasia",
    "Featured",
    "Headlines",
    "Middle East",
    "News",
    "NEWS BY TOPIC",
    "News Categories",
    "REGIONAL NEWS"
  ]
};

$scope.myArray = ['Featured', 'Headlines', 'News'];
```

I want to get everything from `c` which is **not** contained in the `myArray`.

I've tried with writing some functions, but I get my app really slow, because of a lot requests.

So, can I just somehow pass my array, and let Angular goes through every single item in that array and compare it with the current value?

Comment: You can write a custom filter, check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvfq6mrh/1/) for a working example

Comment: it depends on how `i.categories` look like, just post it, is it a normal object or nested object or an array?

Comment: @nivas I have updated my question with **i.categories**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use a custom filter, like the following:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('notInArray', function($filter) {
    return function(list, arrayFilter) {
        if(arrayFilter) {
            return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem) {
                return arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem) == -1;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Use it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='c in i.categories | notInArray:myArray'>{{c}}</div>
```

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/8Lbmq2kn/1/)

---

```js
angular.module('Test', []).filter('notInArray', function($filter) {
    return function(list, arrayFilter) {
        if(arrayFilter) {
            return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem) {
                return arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem) == -1;
            });
        }
    };
});

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.i = {categories: [
      "Europe & Eurasia",
      "Featured",
      "Headlines",
      "Middle East",
      "News",
      "NEWS BY TOPIC",
      "News Categories",
      "REGIONAL NEWS"
  ]};
  
  $scope.myArray = ['Featured', 'Headlines', 'News'];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='Test'>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body ng-controller='Ctrl'>
  <div ng-repeat='c in i.categories | notInArray:myArray'>{{c}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's what I want! :)
But, how to apply this on my example, take a look at the array on which my filter has to be applied. I have no id's. It is not an object, it is array..

Comment: That's it. Thanks mate! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this also.

```
angular.module('App.filters', []).filter('companyFilter', [function () {
    return function (arr, selArr) {
      var retArr = [];
        angular.forEach(arr, function(v, k){
      var found =0;
            for(var i=0; i<selArr.length; i++){
            if(selArr[i] == v.name){
                    found = 1;
                break;
            }
          }
          if(found == 0){
            retArr.push(v);
          }
      })
      return retArr;
    };
}]);

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="c in categories|filter:customFilter">
{{c}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Indhu, Thanks for the answer. 
I'm wondering where should I add my array, or how could I call it in the given filter?

Thanks

I have called the filter in 
'<div ng-repeat="c in categories| filter:companyFilter"> 
{{c}}
</div>'

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="c in categories | companyFilter :customFilter">`